# How to move x-axis to intercept y-axis at specific value for the bar plot without creating "artificial axes" by geom_hline?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, x-axis

Sorry, if that has been already solved somewhere, but the solutions I've seen so far doesn't really work for me.

Let's say we have a this data and I want to plot it as a bar graph with individual values:

```
library(ggplot2)
seed(42)

data <- data.frame(type = sample(LETTERS[1:2], replace = TRUE, 20), values = runif(20)*c(-1, 1))

ggplot(data, aes(x = type, y = values)) +
 geom_point(size = 5)+
 stat_summary(fun=mean, geom='bar', color = "black", alpha = 0.5) +
 stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se, geom='errorbar', width=0.4, size = 1)+
 theme_classic()
```

Resulting in:
[image]

I want to have x-axis intercepting y-axis at 0 and still have labels for "type" on the bottom.
If I just draw geom_hline at "0" then I have two x-axises which is not really preferrable.

How would you move the actual x-axis here ?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73566140/3358272 for one way using the `ggh4x` package. In general, it seems most other ggplot-native implementations can be rather laborious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be the `ggh4x` package which via  `ggh4x::coord_axes_inside` allows for interior axes:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

set.seed(42)

data <- data.frame(type = sample(LETTERS[1:2], replace = TRUE, 20), values = runif(20)*c(-1, 1))

ggplot(data, aes(x = type, y = values)) +
  geom_point(size = 5)+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom='bar', color = "black", alpha = 0.5) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se, geom='errorbar', width=0.4, size = 1) +
  coord_axes_inside() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]